# The TCP/IP connection to the host *** has failed. Error: No Buffer space available(maximum connections reached?) connect

Tags: java, sql-server, windows, tcp, connection-pooling

I have a standalone java application and backend is SQL Server 2012. We have 6 threads which will run continously for every 2 seconds and it will query the database and will close the connection. For each minute we will open 30 connections and close them.

When we run the application in **Windows 2008 R2 Standard/Windows 2010(laptop)/Windows 2012 Server Standard**, it is working fine. But if we run our application on **Windows 2007/Windows 2008 Server R2 datacenter SP1**, number of connections are increasing rapidly and we are getting the error in the title. Once we get this error, we are unable to create new connections and additionally **Remote Desktop to the application server is also not working** and we have to restart the server.

We have checked for any connection leaks in our code, but we dont find any.

```
Application details:
Java version used : 1.6 Update 30,
JDBC driver used: sqljdb4.jar
```

We are using connection pooling while getting connections. Below is the code for getting connections

```
dataSource.getPooledConnection().getConnection();
```

From the management studio, we are checking number of connections with below query.

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

We have installed the hotfix 
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2577795. 
But still the issue is repeating.

Can you suggest what needs to be done in this case?